2024 Community Moderator Election
The 2024 Community Moderator Election is now underway!
Community moderator elections have three phases:

Nomination phase
Primary phase
Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.
Please visit the official election page at
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election
for more detail, and to participate!
If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged election.

The nomination page appears to only allow self nominations, not nominations for other members.  Am I misreading it?

Yeah I would not object to changing that… would be happy to nominate others. I’m worried some people are too humble to nominate themselves!

Related: Upcoming moderator election, which explain that the goal of the election is to increase the number of moderators from three to four.

Proposal: Open more moderator positions.  Three halves make a whole?

@Dcleve Nominating other people is something I have only seen near the end of a stie's Private Beta phase, when "pro temporary moderators" are appointed. The community publishes nominations on a meta question, and a CM then makes a selection. In proper elections, the only thing you can do is nominate yourself or ask other people to nominate themselves.

A chat has been opened to post questions to the mod candidates.  Not much activity there yet.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154893/2024-philosophy-stack-exchange-moderator-election-chat


I nominate Philip Klöcking as moderator.
Philip is one of our present moderators. I appreciate his excellent
work during the last years.

I also nominate Marco Ocram and the present moderator Geoffrey
Thomas as new/continuing moderators.
I have seen that both show by example what I consider to be clear
and helpful answers and comments – one of them since nearly two
years, the other several years ago - before adopting his present job
as a moderator.
I am also confident that both participants could raise the level of
discussion by throwing in from time to time some thought-provoking
question. And also by repudiating those kind of questions, which are
either wide of the mark or which show that the OP misses any effort
of own thought.



Thanks for the merits but it really is about getting additional personel to share the workload between more people than it is currently the case

Zero people have nominated themselves. I hope there is a way to change it so we can nominate others?
Otherwise, I’m casting a bit of a wider net to encourage these people to nominate themselves!

Bumble
J D
Lowri
Dcleve
Conifold
Kristian Berry
causative
Mauro ALLEGRANZA
Corbin
Anyone who is actually a philosophy academic, even if they only participate intermittently

Feel free to say you nominated yourself on my behalf.

How would nominating others even work here?  I assume they are holding an election because they could use the help.  The community cant just choose someone to help who hasn't already volunteered their time to do so.  It's self-nominations because the alternative doesnt really make sense.

@JMac require nominess to Accept a nomination before putting them on the ballot.
